# How to fix the this vertical slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adapting this vertical slider for an pessoal project, but when i click into up or down arrow this works but without any animation. I wanted it to happen a up or down glide smooth   depending on the clicked button. This the adapted JS:

```
// JavaScript Document
 $(function() {
      $("section#canais").hover(function() {
           $("section#buttonsubir").fadeIn();
           $("section#buttondescer").fadeIn();
      }, function(){
           $("section#buttonsubir").fadeOut();
           $("section#buttondescer").fadeOut();     
      });

      $(".cnext").click(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           $("section#canais ul").css({'height' : ''}).animate({top:275},  function(){
                $("#canais ul li").last().after($("#canais ul li").first());
                $(this).css({'down':'0', 'height':'auto'});     
           });
      });

      $(".cprev").click(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           $("#canais ul li").first().before($("#canais ul li").last().css({'top':-275}) );
           $("section#canais ul").css({'height':''}).animate({top:275}, function(){
                $("#canais ul li").first().css({'margin-left':'0'});    
                $(this).css({'left':'0', 'height':'auto'});
           });
       });
  });
```

Here's my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U8698/). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change a few things - first you need the ul to be positioned absolutely:

```
#left-content #canais-links {
    position:absolute;
}
```

Then you need to fix your jQuery (the animation should be `36px` as that is the height of your `li`s: in your css)

```
$(".cnext").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("section#canais ul").css({
        'height': ''
    }).animate({
        top: 36 + "px"
    }, function () {
        $("#canais ul li").last().insertBefore($("#canais ul li").first());
        $(this).css({
            'top': 0
        });
    });
});


$(".cprev").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("section#canais ul").css({
        'height': ''
    }).animate({
        top: -36 + "px"
    }, function () {
        $("#canais ul li").first().insertAfter($("#canais ul li").last());
        $(this).css({
            'top': 0
        });
    });
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/U8698/8/)

You may want to wrap your ul in a div with a set height and overflow hidden so you can't see the divs once it goes up / down

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U8698/14)

Comment: Ok @Pete, but i need a moviment like this: http://jsfiddle.net/natnaydenova/7uXPx/

Answer (score 0):

Another option...which would allow you to display all five items at once would be to use clone() and then remove the hidden element after the animation was completed.  An example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/5Y54k/

I like the approach from Pete a lot but some benefits of this approach is that it uses css for showing and hiding the up and down arrows, reducing your jQuery code and because it's not dependent on positioning, it winds up making your markup and css smaller as well.

HTML:

```
<div id="left-content">
    <div id="img-canais"></div> 
    <a href="#" class="cprev direction">UP</a>
    <ul id="canais-links">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Page 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Page 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Page 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Page 4</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Page 5</a>
        </li>
    </ul> 
    <a href="#" class="cnext direction">DOWN</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left-content {
    width: 203px;
}
.direction {
    opacity: 0;
    transition:opacity .25s linear;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 203px;
}
#left-content:hover .direction {
    opacity: 1;
}
#canais-links {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 25px 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 300px;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#canais-links li {
    height: 36px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #253B6B;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
#canais-links li a {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    height: 36px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.cprev').click(function () {
    $('#canais-links li:first-child').clone().insertAfter('#canais-links li:last-child');
    $('li:first-child').slideUp('slow', function(){
        $('li:first-child').remove();
    });
});
$('.cnext').click(function () {
    var copieditem = $('#canais-links li:last-child').clone()
    copieditem.insertBefore('#canais-links li:first-child').hide();
    $('li:first-child').slideDown('slow', function(){
        $('li:last-child').remove();
    });
});
```